# Invalid signature in Django Rest Frameworl JWT

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

I've created a custom login view to override obtain_jwt_token view as followed.

```
class LoginView(ObtainJSONWebToken):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = User.objects.using(self.request.session.get('shop')).get(mobile=str(request.data['mobile']))
        if not user.check_password(request.data['password']):
            return Response({'Error': "Invalid mobile or password"}, status="400")
        exp = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=settings.TOKEN_EXP_TIME)
        exp = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(exp))
        orig_iat = int(datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now()))
        if user:
            payload = {
                'user_id': user.id,
                "username": user.mobile,
                "exp": exp,
                "email": "",
                'mobile': user.mobile,
                "orig_iat": orig_iat
            }
           jwt_token = {'token': jwt.encode(payload, settings.SECRET_KEY)}
           return Response(jwt_token, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'Error': "Invalid credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
```

after login token will created successfully but when I want to call an API (from postman) get `{"detail": "Invalid signature."}` error.

I'm using my API using get method and I've added `JWT MY_TOKEN` in `Authorization` in header.
Any idea?

Comment: You could try to use `Bearer YOUR_TOKEN` instead of `JWT MY_TOKEN`.

Comment: I did but get same error. I've also add `'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',` in `JWT_AUTH` settings.

Comment: I think you should encode your payload with `jwt_encode_handler`. This will return a token which was encoded with the same algorithm and keys as drf-jwt token verifier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encode your payload with jwt_encode_handler. See the example below.

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings


jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER


class LoginView(ObtainJSONWebToken):
     def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        jwt_token = {'token': jwt_encode_handler(payload)}
        ...
```